# Ajax not sending PHP POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following ajax script to POST data back after re-sorting the rows (which works fine). I'm not getting anything in the `alert(data)` that is being shown once I drag-and-drop the row. It should show me what it's trying to pass to the 'refresh_order.php' file.

I am NOT a jQuery or ajax expert -- I found this bit of code online and the first part works for me (the dragging and dropping) but I don't know what's wrong with the ajax that posts the data back to MySQL.

What do I need to do to fix this?

```
$('tbody').sortable({
    cancel: ":input,button,[contenteditable]",
    axis: "y",
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

         alert(data);  // Sent to server

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'refresh_order.php',
            success: function(response) {
             //    alert(response);   // Server response
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[I have looked through most of the posts here on Stack Overflow and seen nothing that helps my situation. I even tried to reach out to the person who I got the code from but haven't received a response.]

Comment: Ok, so your problem happens before $.ajax, meaning **this isn't an ajax problem**?

Comment: The problem is more likely that you're not retrieving the data correctly, instead of an AJAX issue. Are you sure `this` in the `update` event handler refers to the right element?

Comment: if this is a db-related issue also, you should post the code for it, including the html

Comment: @KevinB: I don't know. I just know that the alert that should show me what is being sent is empty. I don't know why that is.

Comment: Then yes, this isn't an ajax problem. You can remove the ajax request and you'll still have the same problem. `var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');` is likely incorrect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I'm not sure what the `this` refers to in this statement. I have id's in my <tr> lines that read "<tr trid='item_" <php for row number> ">. I admit I'm confused.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas Try `console.log(this)` to see what `this` refers to.

Comment: @KevinB: If this isn't an ajax issue, how do I get the POST data back to PHP?

Comment: well, first you have to get data... otherwise, just like you are. http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Comment: @JasonP: It says "[object HTMLTableSectionElement]" -- I don't know what this means.

Comment: So what should `this` refer to in the statement `var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize):

*Note: If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes "foo_1", "foo_5", "foo_2" will serialize to "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2". You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example "foo=1", "foo-1", and "foo_1" all serialize to "foo[]=1".*

I assume your `tr` elements are missing the `id` attributes in the appropriate format. Here's a working example:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr_1">
      <td>r1c1</td>
      <td>r1c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2">
      <td>r2c1</td>
      <td>r2c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
$('tbody').sortable({
  cancel: ":input,button,[contenteditable]",
  axis: "y",
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwxmfzs5/

Comment: The part that solved my issue was changing the `<tr trid=...` to `<tr id=...`. As soon as I did that, everything else fell into place.